# Azure ML Studio Compute VM constantly bogging down and needs rebooting

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using a VM (Standard_D16s_v3 (16 cores, 64 GB RAM, 128 GB disk)) in Azure ML Studio to do data science work. I'm connecting through the VS Code link in the ML Studio browser. I'm working in a github repo that has a fairly deep file structure and a lot of untracked files from intermediate work. A lot of those files can be large, GB size. Unsure if those are contributing.

The problem is it is usually fairly slow, and after a short time of work (maybe an hour or two) it becomes so slow to become unusable and I have to restart it. It's also always very slow to run an Azure Function locally or to scan for Azure functions. Python venv is also very slow to create, it takes about a minute when it should be more like 10 seconds to create a venv.

One of the biggest problems is Jupyter notebooks will work for a while, but then tend to slow down, and eventually it shows that a cell is running but from `htop` monitoring I don't think anything is actually running. Other times, simple things like executing a print statement to test if it's working will take 10 seconds to run. Stranger yet, it'll run through for 10s while the timer ticks on, then when it's completed, it'll change the timer to 0.7s or something short.

I've looked at the disk usage, and not really sure what the different mounts are but the HDDs that I think are being used for the OS are only about half full. However, we do seem to have a shared drive between everyone working in the ML workspace, since we all have our own folders under code/Users/.

A few times, it has shown a red X on the machine saying the a node failed to start or the primary disk ran out of space. At one point I was writing a lot of big files to /tmp which I assume caused this "disk full" error.

Any ideas why this might be happening, or what else to troubleshoot? I've tried creating new machines (albeit with the same instance type, Standard_D16s_v3) but they seem to have the same issues.

Comment: And yes, I know one of the first next things to try is creating another instance type that's not Standard_D16s_v3.

Comment: I have the exact same issue... it works fine for about an hour, and then something as stupid as running git status takes half an hour... Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @Aleksandra I found that it can be due to slow internet, but also just reloading the window helps. Also make sure you are using ~localfiles and not ~cloudfiles. Cloudfiles is a network drive that is very slow, especially with lots of files like with git or venv. Localfiles is very limited in space though, only 120GB total size, so you can use /mnt but that gets destroyed upon every shutdown, so you have to copy/rsync it every time you shutdown/startup to preserve data there.

Comment: Thanks @wordsforthewise for the info related to `localfiles`. It saves a lot of time on my side.